# Select for Teradata Primary/Foreign key relationship

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key, teradata

Im in the process of learning to properly pull appropriate metadata from a Teradata database and a large part of what I need is to pull all existing primary/foreign keys within a database. I am still very much a beginner with Teradata as well as big data in general, so a simplified explanation would be nice.

A simplified version of a select statement would also be incredibly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Foreign Keys: **dbc.All_RI_ParentsV[X]**

PK/Unique: **dbc.IndicesV[X]**. Unique Indexes got a *UniqueFlag* **Y**, if it was defined as a PK in the Create Table *IndexType* will be **P**. Multi-column indexes got one row per column all sharing the same *IndexNumber*, **1** is always the PI.

But as Teradata is a DWH you might have tables without defined PK and you will hardly find any defined FKs.